# How to load comma separated data into R?

Tags: r, load

I have a flat file like this:

```
   x1,   x2,   x3,   x4,   x5
0.438,0.498,3.625,3.645,5.000
2.918,5.000,2.351,2.332,2.643
1.698,1.687,1.698,1.717,1.744
0.593,0.502,0.493,0.504,0.445
0.431,0.444,0.440,0.429,1.0
0.438,0.498,3.625,3.648,5.000
```

How do I load it in R.

I have tried to do this

```
> x <- read.table("C:\\flatFile.txt", header=TRUE)
```

but after I do some operation I get error like

```
> colSums(x)
Error in colSums(x) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Comment: `?read.csv`.  May I recommend that you spend some time browsing some general R introductions?  I realize that http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf doesn't have great coverage, but there are **loads** of documents at various levels of detail and designed for various different audiences at http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html (PS, maybe I should take a break from StackOverflow for a bit -- I seem to be getting grumpy)

Comment: sorry, but I dont seem to find how to read correctly the data, commas are the problem....?

Comment: I agree with Ben Bolker, but I want to add that you should ?read.table and ?colSums (ie, consult the R help files).  Anyway, use read.csv() instead.

Comment: @Ben Bolker: You forgot the obvious [R Data Import/Export](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at the help on `read.table` you'll discover some extra functions that are essentially `read.table` with different defaults.  If you tend to read in lots of files that would be best read in using those defaults then use them instead of `read.table` for conciseness.

This code will read in your file

```
x <- read.table("C:\\flatFile.txt", header=TRUE, sep = ',')
```

or this code

```
x <- read.csv("C:\\flatFile.txt")
```

Note that, while you can set any of the features of these `read.table` based commands just like `read.table`, it is rather pointless to use them and reiterate the default settings.  For example, don't bother with `read.csv` if you're then going to also be setting `header = TRUE`, and/or, `sep = ','` all of the time as well.  You might as well just use `read.table` in that case.

Comment: Read.table is preferable wherein data is unorganized, every columns contains 2 to 3 tags with comma separation in between, however, if data is well organized then read.csv is good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the colClasses option to read.csv. Like this:

```
x <- read.csv("C:\\flatFile.txt", head=TRUE, colClasses=c("numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric"))
```

Comment: ???? `header=TRUE` (which is how `head=TRUE` will be interpreted, via partial argument matching) is the default for `read.csv`, as is the interpretation of the columns as numeric if they contain all numeric values.  I don't see how your suggestion is any different from `x <- read.csv("C:\\flatFile.txt")` *if* the data are structured as above.  `read.csv` is the key.

Comment: I was thinking that R was somehow getting confused by the input data and needed to be told what the input type was.

Comment: I think it's best in these cases to try to understand exactly what the problem is.  R seems magical enough as it is without adding confusion ... :-)